# How to override Android lifecycle related functions from within a Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova

Adding a native functionality from a regular Android app into my Cordova plugin I found that I need to do:

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        bindService(Intents.getComponentIntent(Intents.COMPONENT_POYNT_SECOND_SCREEN_SERVICE),
                secondScreenServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

The problem is that I can't copy that on my class that extends CordovaPlugin since the method onResume is not in there:

```
public class MyThing extends CordovaPlugin {
  //MY CODE, THERE IS NO METHOD onResume in CordovaPlugin class
}
```

Doing some research I was not able to find much information, [here](https://www.polyglotprogramminginc.com/interacting-with-the-android-lifecycle-in-a-cordova-plugin/) they propose extending the ServiceConnection class, but that is beyond my limited understanding of the Android native development.

I know Cordova expose some callbacks in the javascript side for the application lifecycle, I could create a hook in my plugin to react from a JS call when onResume happens, BUT I need to execute bindService which is a function not available in my class... Is there maybe another way to execute that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an abstract onResume() method](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaPlugin.java#L151) in the CordovaPlugin class which you can override like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume(boolean multitasking) {
    super.onResume(multitasking);
    // Do your stuff here
}
```